# .net c# zeromq request reply simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

I am relatively new to ZeroMq.

What i want to do is send requests and receive replies at the same time.
I read a lot of examples and the ZeroMq guide but i dont know how to achieve this.

Currently my code looks this way:

```
public void SendRequestAsync<T>(T request)
  {
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
        using (ZmqSocket socket = _context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ))
        {
           string endPoint = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}", ServiceIpAddress, Port);
           socket.Connect(endPoint);

           var serializer = new XmlSerializer(request.GetType());

           using (var byteStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
              serializer.Serialize(byteStream, request);
              socket.Send(byteStream.ToArray());
           }
        }
     });

     if (!_isListening)
     {
        StartListeningForReplies();
     }
  }

  private void StartListeningForReplies()
  {
     _responseThread = new Thread(ReplyThreadStart);
     _responseThread.Start();

     _isListening = true;
  }

  private void ReplyThreadStart()
  {
     using (var replySocket = _context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ))
     {
        string endPoint = string.Format("tcp://*:{0}", Port);
        replySocket.Bind(endPoint);

        while (!_listeningAborted)
        {
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           replySocket.Receive(buffer);

           // put into queue for processing
        }
     }
  }
```

I have created a single context before and use this context to create the sockets.

Do i need to use different ports for sending and receiving, and yet another port for publishing?

Please help.

Comment: Do you understand the idea behind different kind of socket (REP / REQ / DEALER / ROUTER / PUB / SUB ) ?

Comment: I already got my implementation right. And yes know i know the difference now.Do i need to close this qquestion now?